# NASM with Bochs - Assembly - Printing a string

Tags: assembly, nasm, boot, bochs

I want to print a string, and am using NASM Assembly, Bochs to run the program, and have two simple files. I am making a very simple boot sector to start learning Assembly. I am attempting to teach myself, and am using this PDF: 
https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf
I am attempting to create my own string-printing function.

Problem:

```
; Question 4
; Put together all of the ideas in this section to make a self-contained function for printing
; null-terminated strings, that can be used as follows:
;
; A boot sector that prints a string using our function.
;
[org 0x7c00] ; Tell the assembler where this code will be loaded
mov bx, HELLO_MSG ; Use BX as a parameter to our function , so
call print_string ; we can specify the address of a string.
mov bx, GOODBYE_MSG
call print_string
jmp $ ; Hang
%include "print_string.asm"
; Data
HELLO_MSG:
db ’Hello , World!’, 0 ; <-- The zero on the end tells our routine
; when to stop printing characters.
GOODBYE_MSG:
db ’Goodbye!’, 0
; Padding and magic number.
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
; For good marks, make sure the function is careful when modifying registers and that
; you fully comment the code to demonstrate your understanding.
```

My code:

bootsect.asm

```
    org 0x7c00 ; Start at boot sector. Allows us to add offset for labels efficiently


    mov bx, loading_sys_msg
    calltest:
    call str_out
    ;jmp calltest

    jmp $ ; Jump forever. Because end of program lol

; Includes
    %include "str_out.asm"

; Database Resources

    loading_sys_msg:
    db 'Loading OIK v0.0.1', 0

; Padding and magic BIOS number.

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
`
```

str_out.asm

```
;
; String-printing function
;
str_out:
pusha
pop bx
;add bx, 0x7c00 ; Adds current address if boot sect and no org called (not used)
mov ah, 0x0e    ; BIOS teletyping for 0x10 interrupt
mov ax, 0x00    ;prep counter
mov al, [bx]    ; character to print placed in al (bx address contents)
prnt:                   ; printing loop
int 0x10            ; interrupt print
add ax, 0x01    ; add to counter for removal afterwards
add bx, 0x01    ; move bx address forward by 1
mov al, [bx]    ; character to print placed in al (bx address contents)
cmp al, 0           ; Compare [al -?- 0]
jg prnt             ; If greater, jump to print
sub bx, ax      ;remove the counter amount
;sub bx, 0x7c00 ;remove address addition if used earlier (not used)
push bx
popa
```

Bochs config:

```
# Tell bochs to use our boot sector code as though it were
# a floppy disk inserted into a computer at boot time.
floppya: 1_44=boot_sect.bin, status=inserted
boot: a
```

When Bochs boots, the screen clears and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

(Thanks to Jester for telling me I didn't state the problem. I am still new to Stack Overflow.)

Comment: You forgot to mention what the problem is ... Also, bochs has a built-in debugger, make sure you use it. PS: `pusha; pop bx` is bad practice and likely doesn't do what you think it does (of course you didn't write a comment what you want that to do)

Comment: I'll take a look at the debugger, thanks for the advice. When doing `pusha; pop bx` I intended to push all vars into the stack and only take out bx. I'll try pushing in all vars other than bx instead and pop them out when I'm done.

Comment: `pop bx` does not search out the original value of `bx` from the ones pushed, it simply removes the topmost item from the stack. Due to how `pusha` works, that's not gonna be `bx`. Anyway, `pusha` does not change `bx`, the value is still there so you don't need to `pop`.

Answer (score 1):

`str_out` is missing a RET instruction, but the lack of display is because you trash AH

```
mov ah, 0x0e    ; BIOS teletyping for 0x10 interrupt
mov ax, 0x00    ;prep counter
```

Usually I don't give an example to exercises, but in this case, you've made a reasonable effort and one can sort of get your logic.

```
            org     0x7c00

            mov     bx, Msg
            call    str_out
            hlt
            jmp     $ - 1

str_out:    mov     ah, 0x0e
prnt:       mov     al, [bx]
            int     0x10
            add     bx, 0x01
            cmp     al, 0
            jg      prnt
            ret

  Msg:      db      'Loading OIK v0.0.1', 0

    times 510-($-$$) db 0
        dw  0xaa55
```

Not exactly sure what is meant by **make sure the function is careful when modifying registers**, but this example does work. As this is essentially a carbon copy of your code, all you need to do is document it, but there are two idiosyncrasies that you might be asked about. Why did you use the instruction(s) and why are they in that order.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I am not quite sure what you mean by trashing, is AX what you mean? (tested and yep it is! I'm going to read up on registers before moving ahead, I think what it meant by being careful was don't use registers you don't understand...) Also, I noticed you included the function in the code. I guess that's a preferential thing in a way (along with convenience/accessibility vs one binary), as is our difference in formatting. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Kohrokho Yes, trashing means in this case you set AH=14 and then in the next instruction, you erase it.  Although I agree with using `%include`, I would recommend the formatting style as once you get to the point where you have thousands of lines of code, it does make a difference.  No argument though, no matter how you do it, if the result is error free code and it's easy for you to maintain, then however you get that to be , it's all good.